# Find and Kill PID from Previous Phoenix Session [Phoenix/Elixir]

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, pid, phoenix-live-view

## To Stop Processes Resulting from `mix phx.server` Command in Previous Session

- I ran `mix phx.server`
- I did not type `ctrl-c` x2 to terminate the resulting processes
- I quit the my text editor
- I try to rerun `mix phx.server` and get this error:

[image: erro message]

### What I've Tried

#### To View the Process

- `lsof -i :4000/:5432/:8080`
- netstat commands
- Activity Monitor

#### To Kill the Process

- `kill -9 <PID>` to no avail because I still can't find the right PID for that previously run phoenix session.

Also, the error for "failed to start child" is not the cause of me being unable to run `mix phx.server` it's because I didn't close the previously existing process

Comment: That first error looks like the database isn't running...

Comment: “it's because I didn't close the previously existing process”—I honestly doubt it.